# Share browser sessions selenium

Tags: automation, session-cookies, data-transfer

I’m currently looking for a method of transferring a session with all cookies to another pc, when I run my script and it gets where I want it to go is it possible to transfer that session to someone in another country?

I’ve seen people using chrome extensions but I have no knowledge whatsoever on how to do it

I’ve tried manually downloading cookie editor and saving the cookies and transferring to another browser then entering the url and it works, but is there a way to automate that?